# retrieving and displaying mongodb document content in laravel based on Lat/Long and distance

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

1)  In my table several record based on lat/long and distance I am
    getting record.

```
 db.user_address.find({location: { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type:
    "Point", coordinates: [74.365484,31.516063] }, $maxDistance:
    100}}}).pretty()
```

But same time when why I am doing with laravel its displaying all
records.

```
$r = array('location'=>array( '$near' => array('$geometry' => array(
'type' => "Point", 'coordinates' => array(74.365484,31.516063)), 
'maxDistance' => 100 )));
            $ProviderInRange = UserAddress::where($r)->get();
```

Please help while I am using laravel to mongodb to get record.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some text,

```
$r = array("location"=> 
            array( "$near" => 
                    array("$geometry" => 
                            array( "type" => "Point", 
                                   "coordinates" => array(74.365484,31.516063)), 
                                   "$maxDistance" => 100 ))); 

$ProviderInRange = UserAddress::where($r)->get();
```

It's working fine. Please have a look [See Here](http://www.codehicode.com)